# Why does the same select statement have different costs in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, performance, query-optimization

Recently I used Oracle 11g database to do my homework. I had 12 tables, like  trip_data_11 and trip_data_12. 
They have same structure and the number of records is almost the same. I created the same indexes on each table.
So for trip_data_11 table:

```
create index pick_add_11 on trip_data_11(pickup_longitude,pickup_latitude);
create index drop_add_11 on trip_data_11(dropoff_longitude,dropoff_latitude);
```

The same operation to trip_data_12.

Then I used the following select statement to select the taxi numbers per day.

```
SELECT
   COUNT(DISTINCT(td.medallion)) AS taxi_num
FROM
   SYS.TRIP_DATA_11 td
WHERE 
    (td.pickup_longitude >= -74.2593 AND td.pickup_longitude <= -73.7011
     AND td.pickup_latitude >= 40.4770 AND td.pickup_latitude <= 40.9171
    )
    AND
    (td.dropoff_longitude >= -74.2593 AND td.dropoff_longitude <=    -73.7011
    AND td.dropoff_latitude >= 40.4770 AND td.dropoff_latitude <=  40.9171
  )
 AND
     td.trip_distance > 0
 AND
     td.passenger_count > 0
  GROUP BY 
      regexp_substr(td.pickup_datetime,'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}')
  ORDER BY
      regexp_substr(td.pickup_datetime,'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}');
```

It costs 38sec。When I changed the table name to SYS.TRIP_DATA_12, the problem coming, it costs more than 2 hours.
What's more, it did not end. I don't know why.

Today I ask my classmate and he said: clear the cache. So I used the following  statements to do it.

```
alter system flush shared_pool;
alter system flush buffer_cache;
alter system flush global context;
```

Now when I use the same select statement for SYS.TRIP_DATA_11 I get the same poor performance like SYS.TRIP_DATA_12. Why?

Comment: First, never create objects in the `SYS` schema.  `SYS` behaves differently from other schemas.  Don't know if that is an issue here but it can't help.  How big are the tables?  Are the statistics on the tables and indexes accurate and up to date?

Comment: Thanks for your advice. But I created all tables use sys account.The tables contains almost 14,000,000.Yesteday, I created the table and use Ttoad to load the data, then created indexs. So the statistics on the tables and indexes are accurate and up to date.

Comment: If you're going to use the `SYS` account, expect that you're likely to encounter odd behaviors that may look like bugs.  At what point in this process did you gather statistics?

Comment: Just gaining the number of taxi per day in one month.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like your classmate was having a good joke at your expense.

Clearly your query was only performing well because you had a warm buffer cache full of all the data you needed from TRIP_DATA_11.  By flushing the caches you have zapped all that, and now you have the same bad performance for all tables.

Tuning queries is hard, because there are lots of possibilities.  [Please read the documentation on it](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10822/tdppt_partfour.htm#BABJDBHB).

To pick just one thing:  you're searching ranges, which is problematic.  How many rows fill `-74.2593 to -73.7011` ?  It might be a lot more than say `-71.00 to -68.59` even though that's a broader range.   Understanding your data - its volume, its distribution and its skew - is crucial.

As a first step learn how to use EXPLAIN PLAN.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9010.htm#SQLRF01601).  To get better plans, gather statistics on your tables and their indexes, using DBMS_STATS package.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_stats.htm#ARPLS059).

One tip.  Oracle only uses one index to access a table.  So it will choose `pick_add_11` *or* `drop_add_11` but not both.  It will then read all the matching records from the table and filter them by the other criteria.  You may get much better performance from a index designed to service this query:

```
create  index add_11 on trip_data_11
   (pickup_longitude
    , pickup_latitude
    , dropoff_longitude
    , dropoff_latitude
    , trip_distance 
    , passenger_count )
;
```

The select statement will execute the entire filter against this index and only  touch the table to get the MEDALLION values. (You could add `medallion` to the index too).  Experiment with the column order.  As latitude has a narrower range than longitude probably that should go first; maybe drop-off value should appear before pick-up.  You want an index in which the greatest number of related records are clustered together.

Indexes like this can be an overhead, so we wouldn't want to maintain too many of them in real life.  But they are a valuable technique for tuning expensive queries which are run frequently.

---

Oh, and @Justin's right: don't use SYS for doing application work.  Even for a school assignment you should create a fresh schema and create your tables, etc in that.

Comment: Thanks for giving me losts of tips and editing my questions. Every table stored as cvs format,
its size 2.5G. I used Toad to load the data to db, the the number of records is almost 14,000,000
for each table.
    Secondly, the homework requires the longitude from -74.2593 to -73.7011 and the latitude
40.4770 from 40.9171.

Comment: @APU,I used sys account to create a user,and created tempspace and defaultspace to it.Then created the trip_data_12 table and loaded data.Taking your tips created the index , however, the select statements cost 3hours more,but not end. I didn't know why using the select satements for trip_data_11 first time just costs 38sec. At that time, the db also has no cache for it.

Comment: @yunfeng - I'm afraid there is no way I can diagnose performance problems in your code at a distance.  You'll have to ask your teacher or a more knowledgeable classmate for help.

Comment: @APU,Thanks,I try it agian.